# Acquiring new IP when changing subnet

Tags: dhcp

DHCP allows a computer to acquire a new IP address whenever it moves to a new subnet. Why is this not always enough to address the communications needs of mobile hosts?

Comment: could you elaborate ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit vague, but one reason why DHCP might not be sufficient is in the case where the mobile device needs to maintain a connection to another host (a server, for example) while moving from one network to another.  If the mobile device gets a new IP address, the connection to the server would be broken, as the device must initiate a new connection to the server.  Also, the time it takes for the client to recognize it is on a new network and receive a new address may be too long for some applications.